# Look for a job while waiting to be laid off

Tags: job-search, layoff

So we've been informed that there will be a massive round of layoffs in a few months and that management still hasn't decided on who to lay off. I'm guessing that the chances of me being laid off are higher than most since I'm relatively new to the company.

My question is that since it will be a few months before I know if I will be laid off and since I'll have about two months after that before I have to leave the job, should I start looking for work now?

I'm worried that if I get laid off and wait until then I will have to compete with 3000+ laid off developers.

Comment: Yes... yes you should. The 3000+ other developers are already doing the same.

Comment: On a side note, I would say make sure you don't mention you may be getting laid off in interviews.  That could lead to a lower offer.

Comment: @Ronnie Considering that this was the highlight of the national news yesterday, I think they will figure it out when they see my CV :p

Comment: @user33276 Assuming your in the US I still don't know what company you are talking about.  Take it for what it is worth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start today.

The goal is to have an firm offer in your hand by the time they announce who is being laid off.

You might even decide to move before you find out, or you might decide to move even if you survive the cuts.

Management knows, or should know, that the stampede out the door has already begun. be glad they gave you months, they could have given you no notice.

Comment: management wants you to find another job and leave of your own accord. It saves them paying you any kind of severance allowance, lowers the number of people they need to kick to the curb, and lowers the stress on the people who have to decide who to lay off. That's why they told you. Well, that and to be nice to you. You decide the relative proportions of each motivation.

Comment: Unless of course the company is covered by the WARN act, in which case they are legally required to give you notice.